# How to explode ans change the array values into key?

Tags: php, arrays

I am having an array like this.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => a~226
            [1] => a~228
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => b~123
            [1] => b~209
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => c~161
            [1] => c~140
        )

)
```

I want to explode this array using ~ symbol and i want value to be a key in php array.i want an array like this.Kindly help me write the code.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [a] => 226
            [a] => 228
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [b] => 123
            [b] => 209
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [c] => 161
            [c] => 140
        )

)
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: You can't create that array, because kes must be unique... two keys in the same array with the same key (e.g. `a` and `a` or `b` and `b`) is not unique

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have such an array.
The keys must be unique (Like Mark Baker say).

You can have something like this:

```
Array
(
    [a] => Array
        (
            [0] => 226
            [1] => 228
        )

    [b] => Array
        (
            [0] => 123
            [1] => 209
        )

    [c] => Array
        (
            [0] => 161
            [1] => 140
        )

)
```

The code to do this:

```
$array = array(
    array("a~226", "a~228"), 
    array("b~123", "b~209"), 
    array("c~161", "c~140")
);

$result = array();

foreach($array as $inner_array) {
    foreach($inner_array as $value) {
        $spitted = explode("~", $value);
        $result[$spitted[0]][] = end($spitted);
    }

}
```

An working example: http://codepad.viper-7.com/znhhqB

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$arr_new  = array();
foreach($arr_main as $key=>$arr)
{
    foreach($arr as $k=>$val)
    {
        $str = explode("~",$val);
        $arr_new[$key][$str[0].$k]=$str[1];
    }
}
```

will maintain the index as  `a0, a1`

Comment: @vascowhite you are right. but code is correct maintain only one index in second array and overlapping the values.

Comment: The code may be correct in some situations, but it isn't in this one.

Comment: @vascowhite i made some changes in code to maintain unique index

Comment: Yes, but it still isn't what was asked for, I guess only the OP can decide if this will suffice :) I would suggest expanding your answer to explain why the OP can't get the array asked for in their example.

Comment: he hasn't enough knowledge about array index thats why he put duplicate index. i am trying to help him only